# How to enable sourcemaps in Vite

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I am using Vite and Vue3 with vue-facing-decorator, and cannot get debugging in Chrome to function properly.

As an example, I have this Vue3 code:

```
get description() {
        debugger;
        let result = '';
        if (!this.localModel.Number || isNaN(this.localModel.Number) || /^\d+$/.test(this.localModel.Number.toString()) == false) {
            return '';
        }           

        result += t('search.periodEditor.actualDateDescription', {
            from: I18nHelper.shortDateTime(this.localModel!.StartDate!),
            to: I18nHelper.shortDateTime(this.localModel!.EndDate!)
        });

        return result;
    }
```

Problem is that Chrome starts debugging the line before the debugger statement, and hovering variables gets wrong results (here the `result` var is an empty string, but devtools tells me that result is the `localModel` object):

[image]

In the vite.config.ts I have enabled sourcemapping:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),      
        vuetify({
            autoImport: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
    },
...
```

In the end of the file I try to debug in Chrome, there is no sourcemap url, so I guess this  could be the problem?

I´ve also tried

```
build: {
            sourcemap: 'inline',
        },
```

But no sourcemap URL is added at the end of the file.